# Can someone explain the toString() method

Tags: java, tostring

I'm trying to get my head round the `toString()` method. I've had a look through google to try and understand the method.

Can someone explain the method?

Comment: Is your title misnamed?

Comment: And what do you not understand about it? It's a method which gives a textual representation of an object. The default implementation isn't terribly useful, but you can override it.

Comment: is it toString() or toSting() and your title says something else??

Comment: It returns a `String` reference that, loosely speaking, represents or describes the object. What that means specifically is up to the object, and it could be anything.

Comment: its just a method that returns a string. by default class name and hash code. You can over ride it. use to give object description/ status (for logging) default method called when you want a string representaion of a class.

Answer (score 2):

All you really need to do is look at the documentation. Taken from [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29):

> Returns a string representation of the object. In general, the toString method returns a string that "textually represents" this object. The result should be a concise but informative representation that is easy for a person to read. It is recommended that all subclasses override this method.

Answer (score 2):

I think you have not read java docs. [Try Reading](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29)

IMO,no one can explain better than the Java Docs.

Answer (score 0):

`toString()` is a method in the `Object` class and you can `override` this method in your class. This method return a `String` which is a text base representation of a Class.

Answer (score 0):

```
Integer x = 5;
System.out.println(x.toString());
```

toString() always returns the String representation of an object.

So here the output will be 5.

Answer (score 0):

toString() method is generally used when you process some data in your program and want to display it in a TextBox.(this answer is in context to TextBox). 
The processed value is converted to String type to be printed in the TextBox.

```
int a = 10;
int b=20;
int c=a+b;
TextBox t1 = new TextBox();
t1.setText (c.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

toString() method is method of object class. It is called when we try to print using System.out.println(). This method give string representation to our object. We can give definition by creating source from eclipse .

for example consider this code snip here I have overridden the toString()

public class Employee {

```
private int id;
private int phoneNo;
public int getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public int getPhoneNo() {
    return phoneNo;
}
public void setPhoneNo(int phoneNo) {
    this.phoneNo = phoneNo;
}
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Employee [id=" + id + ", phoneNo=" + phoneNo + "]";
}
```

}